# JSON Data - In Python How to Print Only Results Where Key = Available

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

First off this is my first post and I'm a noob trying to learn a little Python because I want to view #available campsites and would prefer to code my own program then use some paid website. Below is my code #which prints the results I have shown below. I only want to print the "availabilities": if it shows
"Available" not "Reserved".

Thank you in advanced

```
import json
import urllib.request
import time
    
# download raw json object
url = "https://www.recreation.gov/api/camps/availability/campground/233116/month?start_date=2020-09-01T00%3A00%3A00.000Z"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
    
# parse json object
obj = json.loads(data)

print(json.dumps(obj, indent=1))




{
 "campsites": {
  "90041": {
   "availabilities": {
    "2020-09-01T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-02T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-03T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-04T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-05T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-06T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-07T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-08T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-09T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-10T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-11T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-12T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-13T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-14T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-15T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-16T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-17T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-18T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-19T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-20T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-21T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-22T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-23T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-24T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-25T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-26T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-27T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-28T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-29T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",
    "2020-09-30T00:00:00Z": "Reserved"
   },
   "campsite_id": "90041",
   "campsite_reserve_type": "Site-Specific",
   "campsite_type": "STANDARD NONELECTRIC",
   "capacity_rating": "",
   "loop": "KIRK CREEK CAMPGROUND",
   "max_num_people": 8,
   "min_num_people": 1,
   "quantities": null,
   "site": "030",
   "type_of_use": "Overnight"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several possibilities, here. I think a simple solution is to post-process the data (the `obj`) by simply deleting the entries which aren't `"Available"`. Here is a solution which gives you the same data, only filtering the availabilities:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
result = deepcopy(obj)

for campsite, info in obj["campsites"].items():
    for day, availability in info["availabilities"].items():
        if availability != "Available":
            del result["campsites"][campsite]["availabilities"][day]

print(json.dumps(result, indent=1))
```

If you need an other data structure, I hope you got an idea how to do so.

Modifications while iterating over an object could lead to some trouble. That's why I have created a deep copy (without references) of your `obj`. You have to dump the `result` instead of `obj` then, of course.

For your given data, I haven't found available dates any more, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Unfortunately it looks like the results are showing the availability with no data so I can't tell if the site is available or not. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Here are the results for this code.

{
 "campsites": {
  "90041": {
   "availabilities": {},
   "campsite_id": "90041",
   "campsite_reserve_type": "Site-Specific",
   "campsite_type": "STANDARD NONELECTRIC",
   "capacity_rating": "",

Comment: Sorry.. I also need the date otherwise I don't know what day the site is available.

"2020-09-01T00:00:00Z": "Reserved",   Need to print this where Reserved is Available.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If availability is empty, then there was no available date left. Because all dates not "available" are filtered out. So you *can* say, that there is no available day if you see empty "availabilities". Print out the obj, and you see that there is no available date. That's how I understood your question: *I only want to print the "availabilities": if it shows "Available" not "Reserved".*

Comment: I would like to see all the information printed including the date and site info in the availability shows available. Sorry for the confusion. Your help is greatly appreciated. I have spent a ton on time searching google and can not find an example for this question.

Comment: Looks like its working. The problem seemed to be the json results. I changed the date and it worked. Thanks again!